# Slow down video file to a set duration

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

Say I have a video exactly 25.1 seconds long and a Windows computer with `ffmpeg.exe`. Is there a way to use ffmpeg to slow down *or* speed up a video based off a number I give to it? For example, I want the 25.1 second video to slow down to exactly 24.3 seconds. How would I do that?
Normally, I would use `-filter:v "setpts=SPD*DURATION"`, but that only speeds up or slows down by a multiplier, and not by an absolute number.

Comment: Use `setpts = NewDuration/OldDuration * PTS`, so `setpts=(24.3/25.1)*PTS`

Comment: @Mulvya I was thinking about that, except it was 10 PM when I thought of it. Thanks. ☺

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, the way to do this is with the following command:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=(NewDuration/OldDuration)*PTS" out.mp4`

If the factor is less than 1.0, it will speed up the video, if it is greater than 1.0, it will slow down the video. Also, the "PTS" is an internal variable, so it can be kept as shown without needing to put something in its place. Only the durations need to have numbers entered.

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=(24.3/25.1)*PTS" out.mp4`

Comment: I tested and this worked for a timelapse. I had to cut the extra part of the video though.

Comment: to cut the extra part, you can add -ss 00:00 -to NewDuration right before out.mp4